# while (sqlite3_step(statement1) == SQLITE_ROW) is not working even though both values are equal in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I dont know the exact problem but have been scratching my head for almost 4 hrs now.

```
    if (sqlite3_open([dataBasePath UTF8String], &bookDB) == SQLITE_OK) {


    NSString *Query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM linktable WHERE pageid = 2"];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(bookDB, [Query UTF8String], -1, &statement1, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {

        markupsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

        NSLog(@"sqlite3_step(statement1) is %d",sqlite3_step(statement1));

        while (sqlite3_step(statement1) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSLog(@"yup");

            MarkupData *markUpObject = [[MarkupData alloc] init];

            markUpObject.linkID =  [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement1, 0)] autorelease];
            markUpObject.pageID =  [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement1, 1)] autorelease];
            markUpObject.markupID =  [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement1, 2)] autorelease];
            markUpObject.folioNumber =  [[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement1, 5)] autorelease];


            [markupsArray addObject:markUpObject];
        }
    }
}
```

Here comes the strange thing. The value of `sqlite3_step(statement1)` is 100, so is the value of `SQLITE_ROW`. But even then the while loop is not getting executed. Can any one help me crack this strange scenario please... Just got struck up here.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sqlite query is returning just 1 record, the `sqlite3_step()` actually steps through the record. Since you have your `NSLog` statement executing `sqlite3_step()`, the record is already stepped through here. Hence, your `while` loop won't execute as there are no more rows to step through.

Comment: Thanks for the answer hetal. Can you please tell me what to do in order to solve this problem?

Comment: oooh man.. thanku.. that did the trick... Great answer. +1 for ur answer and accepted that as well.... Thanks again.... :)

Comment: Did you try executing your query via a sqlite manager to see if it returns you records? Or you can try executing "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM linktable WHERE pageid = 2" to see if you are getting records back. I am believing that your "sqlite3_prepare_v2" and "sqlite3_open" are not giving errors.